# Increasing height of jtable dynamically upon insertion of rows

Tags: java, swing

I am having a problem on adjusting the height of a `jtable` whenever I insert rows. I have tried using `setsize()` and `setPreferredScrollableViewportsize()` for both table and `scrollpane` of the table. Could it be a problem in layout manager?

I also tried increasing the size of `jpanel` too upon inserting each row. BTW, the table lies in a panel and that panel lies in a `jDialog`. I am using free design in NetBeans for UI building.

Comment: *"I am using free design.."* I think I see the problem. Use one of the standard layout managers and call me in the morning if there are further problems. But before you call me, [edit] to add a [mcve] of your attempt using layout managers.

Comment: You don't want your JTable to grow as data is being inserted into the JTable. IMHO that's annoying. This is why a JTable has a JScrollPane, so a User can scroll through the table either horizontally or vertically if desired. If the User finds that scrolling is annoying then he/she/it can size the JDialog accordingly to suit their specific needs. The JTable (if anchored properly and a proper layout manager is used) should expand and contract automatically as the JDialog is resized. No idea what your current components layout might be but try the BorderLayout and anchor Panel's accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following... But make sure you editable option is false!

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        final TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
        for(int column=0; column<table.getColumnCount();column++){
            int width = 15;
            for(int row=0; row<table.getRowCount();row++){
                TableCellRenderer render = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component component = table.prepareRenderer(render, row, column);
                width = Math.max(component.getPreferredSize().width+1, width);
            }
            if(width>300){
                width = 300;
                colModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be about the *width* of columns. Besides that: Don't use `<<Table>>`. Use a proper name instead, otherwise people will complain about the invalid/unreadable code.

Comment: Sure Sir... Next time, I will careful for this type of silly mistake... I am new here so I have no idea how to manage the post.
Thank you very much for guiding me sir..!!